# How to create "<" sign in Navigation bar and make more space between status bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I would like to add to my navigation bar "<" sign as back button, but I don't know how can I do that. Second thing is space between the button and battery or time status. How can I do it bigger?

[image: Situation on the picture]

Comment: You've created the navigation bar incorrectly - otherwise it would be taller and there would be more space. How are you creating it? — As for the "<" button, it will be there automatically if there is something to go back to. So clearly there isn't.

Comment: I have created TableViewController, and then I drag and drop Navigation Bar. In another views, where I don't have Table, does it work correctly.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Don't "drag and drop Navigation Bar". Embed in (or push onto) a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your controller in UINavigationController by clicking on Editor in top bar. A navigation bar will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the problem is that you are not using a UINavigationController. Use one. That way, the navigation bar will be taller and the "<" symbol will appear automatically after you push a view controller onto the navigation controller.

Comment: This is a great place to start: Apple View Controller guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH2-SW1